# What is a "scutella of reindeer"?

Tags: terminology

In the film "The Perfect Human Diet" at 32:36, a scientist points to animal remains and states "we've got a scutella of reindeer there."  What is scutella in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scutella refers to shield or plate-like structure on animals ([dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scutella?s=t)), such as the scutes of a turtle shell.  I have never seen reference to scutes or scutella or anything similar on any type of deer, including reindeer.

I have not seen the movie so I do not know the context of usage. My gut reaction is the person was trying to make something sound important or "scientific" when a much simpler (and perhaps more accurate) word would have sufficed.